# $G$ a group where $H$ is a subset of $G$ with index $[G:H]<+\infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a group where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with index $[G:H]< +\infty$. Show if for the element g is an element in G we have $gHg^{-1}$ is a subset of H. Then we must have$ gHg^{-1}=H$.

(This is not necessarily true if $[G:H]= +\infty)$

Just came to this question while looking for problems. I would like to know how to prove this.

Here is what I did

for all $x^2 = e $

$$x\rightarrow x^{-1}=x$$
$$y\rightarrow y^{-1}$$
$$xy\rightarrow (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$$

Let $T_g: x\mapsto g^{-1}(x)(g)$. Let $G: g\mapsto g^{-1}xg = X$ where this is homomorphic
Then $gh\rightarrow T_{gh} (x) = (gh)^{-1}xg$.
Not sure how to solve. Please help.

Comment: I removed the (measure-theory) and (general-topology) tags which were not appropriate.

Comment: @9959: notice $H=ege^{-1}\subset gHg^-1$ and $|gHg^-1|=|H|$

Comment: Where did $T$ suddenly come from. And when you write $Tsub(g)sub(h)$ do you mean $T_{g}T_h$?

Comment: Do you mean $T_{gh}$ by Tsub(g)sub(h)? You can typeset it like this: `$T_{gh}$`.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 3):

If $[G:H]=n$ is finite, $G$ can be written as a disjoint union of $n$ cosets of $H$, $G=\bigcup_{1\le i\le n} a_i H$.  Conjugating this by $g$ expresses $G$ as a disjoint union of $n$ cosets of the subgroup $gHg^{-1}$:
$$G=\bigcup_{1\le i\le n} ga_i H g^{-1}=\bigcup_{1\le i\le n} (ga_ig^{-1})( g H g^{-1}),$$
so $[G:gHg^{-1}]=n$.  However, if $gHg^{-1}\le H$, then also
$$
[G:gHg^{-1}]=[G:H][H:gHg^{-1}].
$$
Cancelling $n$ from both sides then gives $[H:gHg^{-1}]=1$, so $H=gHg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Conjugating by $g$ is an automorphism of $G$. So, if $H$ is a subgroup of finite index then $gHg^{-1}$ is also a subgroup of finite index and $[G:H]=[G:gHg^{-1}]$. Therefore if $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$, then $H=gHg^{-1}$.